# No-argument method on window.external is invoked when checking with typeof

Tags: c#, javascript, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I am trying to display an HTML page with embedded JavaScript code inside a `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` control. The JavaScript code is expected to interact with the embedding environment through the `window.external` object. Before invoking a method on `window.external`, JavaScript is supposed to check for the existance of the method. If it is not there, the code should invoke a generic fallback method.

```
// basic idea
if (typeof(window.external.MyMethod) != 'undefined') {
    window.external.MyMethod(args);
} else {
    window.external.Generic("MyMethod", args);
}
```

However, checking for a no-argument method with `typeof` seems to invoke the method already. That is, if `MyMethod` accepts any positive number of arguments, the code above will work perfectly; but, if `MyMethod` is a no-argument method, then the expression `typeof(window.external.MyMethod)` will not check for its type but invoke it, too.

Is there any work-around to this behavior? Can I somehow escape the expression `window.external.MyMethod` to prevent the method call from occurring?

Comment: Have you tried using typeof as an operator instead of as a function?
`typeof window.external.MyMethod !== "undefined"`

Comment: Anyone answering this question needs to **try their solution with `window.external` on IE** -- regular ways of testing for an object's existence on Javascript do not work for `window.external`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have not debugged your exact situation but I believe my psychic powers can work out what is going on here.

The JScript language makes a distinction between *use* of a function and mere *mention* of it. When you say

```
x = f;
```

that says "assign a reference to the function identified by f to the variable x". It *mentions* f. By contrast,

```
x = f();
```

*uses* f. It means "call the function identified by f and assign the returned value to x."

In short, functions in JScript are essentially what we would think of as *properties of delegate type* in C#.

Some languages do not make this distinction. In VBScript, if you say `x = f` and f is a function, that means to call the function, same as `x = f()`. VBScript does not make a strong distinction syntactically between the use and mention of a function.

The way this is all implemented is we use COM; specifically, we use OLE Automation. When dispatching a field of an object to get its value, the JScript engine passes flags that mean either "property get" or "method invoke", depending on whether it was use or mention.

But suppose your object being dispatched was written with the expectation that it would be called from VB. Perhaps it was written *in VB*. It is perfectly reasonable and legal for a VB object to say "oh, I see you're asking me for the value of this method. Since I don't understand the difference between mentioning a method and using it, I'll just invoke it no matter which flag you pass".

I don't know if there is a workaround, but I'd be willing to bet as much as a dollar that what's happening is *the invoked object is assuming that the caller wants VB semantics.*

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for your excellent reply. I expected something like this to happen behind the scenes since I've read your blog comment from 2004 yesterday (http://discuss.techinterview.org/default.asp?joel.3.18644.7). I guess, that the COM stuff is implemented somewhere inside the WebBrowser control, isn't it? I won't be able to patch in another lookup handling? Or can I mark a method explicitly as "COM visible as method and not property"?

Comment: If this is the case, you can try to play with `IDispatch` implementation in your C# class. First, I would try the `IDispatchImpl` attribute - try setting it to `CompatibleImpl` and `InternalImpl` and see if either way works. Or, you can provide your own implementation of `IDispatch` - mark your object `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]` and have it explicitly implement `IDispatch`. I also suspect (don't really know) that the `IDynamicObject` of .NET 4.0 may be used for `IDispatch` mapping.

Answer (score 7):

I found this

```
if ('MyMethod' in window.external)
```

does not invoke MyMethod

Comment: But this does not help much, the script will fail if `window.external` is not present.

Comment: @funkybro In that case, all you need to do is add an extra check, e.g. `if (window.external && 'MyMethod' in window.external)`.

Comment: true, however if you see my answer below that just doing `window.external` will itself fail on IE.

Comment: While Eric's answer explained the inner workings, this answer actually solve the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these

```
/* Methods for feature testing
 * From http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/feature-detection-state-of-the-art-browser-scripting
 */
function isHostMethod(object, property){
    var t = typeof object[property];
    return t == 'function' ||
    (!!(t == 'object' && object[property])) ||
    t == 'unknown';
}

function isHostObject(object, property){
    return !!(typeof(object[property]) == 'object' && object[property]);
}

if (isHostObject(window.external, "MyMethod")) {....
```

Comment: Hi Sean, your `isHostMethod` doesn't work either. The line `object[property]` still invokes the method.

Answer (score 0):

This effect can be seen in desktop Internet Explorer.  A script such as:

```
for (var i in window) {
    console.log('window.' + i + ' = ' + window[i]);
}
```

will fail as soon as `external` is reached.

It appears that `window.external` is not a regular Javascript object, it is a VBScript object.

So statements such as `window.external` and `window['external']` **are therefore VBScript statements** -- and, as Eric L says, `window.external` in VBScript is equivalent to `window.external()`.

Mighty confusing.  It appears also that this is the only object to behave in such a way on Internet Explorer.

For cross-browser mobile web apps which make use of IE Mobile's `window.external.Notify()` to communicate with native on Windows Phone 8, but which would also want to set `document.location` on iOS, testing for the existence of `window.external.Notify` would seem logical -- but does not work for this reason.

I have not found a way of preventing this; it still happens when specifying `type="text/javascript"` in the `script` tag.

Answer (score 0):

So really the only choice is workarounds:
1) Just do not use 0 parameter functions.
2) Make a checking function (taking a parameter) to detect if there is an external to call to.

```
if (typeof(window.external.HasExternal(null)) != 'undefined')
```

and check that instead of the function if the external functions are either all there or not there.
3) For each parameterless function you want, either make it use a bogus parameter or add a 1 parameter checking function for it if the external code varies in what functions it supports.

Answer (score -1):

I'm actually not sure if it will help, but try `window.external["MyMethod"]`.

If that doesn't help, try to store this value in a variable, and only then check type of that variable. See if that helps.

Comment: Neither variant works, unfortunately. `window.external["MyMethod"]` invokes it, as well as `var f = window.external["MyMethod"]`.